# <xsl:for-each> repeats first row

Tags: xslt, xslt-1.0

Below is what my XML looks like.  I have also copied XSLT and output below. My problem is that, the output is always repeating the same first row. If I add more rows to input XML file then first row would repeat in output file for that many number of rows added.  What could be the reason?

XML:

```
<Loans>
    <Loan>
        <loan_number>123</loan_number>
        <loan_aqn_date>08-01-2016</loan_number>
    </Loan>
    <Loan>
        <loan_number>456</loan_number>
        <loan_aqn_date>10-01-2016</loan_number>
    </Loan>
    <Loan>
        <loan_number>789</loan_number>
        <loan_aqn_date>12-01-2016</loan_number>
    </Loan>
</Loans>
```

Output:

```
loan_number|loan_aqn_date|
123|08-01-2016|
123|08-01-2016|
123|08-01-2016|
```

XSLT:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>loan_number|loan_aqn_date|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Loans/Loan">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(/Loans/Loan/loan_number,'|')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(/Loans/Loan/loan_aqn_date,'|')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Quick correction: I missed closing ">" for "</Loans" in the above post. I do have it correctly as "</Loans>" in my xml file

Comment: I fixed this in an edit.

Comment: There still is a mismatch between the opening and closing tags of `<loan_aqn_date>`12-01-2016`</loan_number>`.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You are using an absolute path for "select" inside loop.
Try this:

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
    <xsl:output method="text" />
    <xsl:template match="/">
        <xsl:text>loan_number|loan_aqn_date|</xsl:text>
        <xsl:for-each select="/Loans/Loan">
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(loan_number,'|')" />
            <xsl:value-of select="concat(loan_aqn_date,'|')" />
        </xsl:for-each>
    </xsl:template>
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Absolute path was the issue. I removed it and kept just the attribute names. It is now working perfectly fine with for-each.  Thanks much Rafael Z.

Answer (score 0):

Replacing the `<for-each>` with a template could make your approach more general.

```
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
  <xsl:output method="text" />
  <xsl:strip-space elements="Loans" />     <!-- Removes surrounding spaces -->

  <xsl:template match="/Loans">
    <xsl:text>loan_number|loan_aqn_date|&#10;</xsl:text>
    <xsl:apply-templates />                <!-- Processes 'Loan' nodes -->
  </xsl:template>    

  <xsl:template match="Loan">
    <xsl:value-of select="concat(loan_number, '|', loan_aqn_date,'|')" />
    <xsl:text>&#10;</xsl:text>             <!-- Adds newlines -->
  </xsl:template>    
</xsl:stylesheet>
```

**Output:**

```
loan_number|loan_aqn_date|
123|08-01-2016|
456|10-01-2016|
789|12-01-2016|
```